# Detecting unconfirmed double spends using bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions, doublespend, mempool

I want to get statistics on how many percentage of unconfirmed tx in the mempool are having attempted double spends and having what value. For this I want to get notification when an unconfirmed tx arrives that is conflicting with existing tx in mempool. I understand that bitcoind will accept the first transaction it sees and reject the next one, can I configure/patch bitcoind to send me notification on such double spend attempt ?

PS: I understand that a double spend can happen by directly including new tx in the next block without ever showing up in unconfirmed tx list. I think that requires direct access to mining pool and enough guarantees that the block will be mined. For my experiment, I am fine with ignoring this case as it has low probability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bitcoind` has a debugging option named `mempoolrej`. You can enable this by adding

```
debug=mempoolrej
```

to your bitcoin.conf file.

This debugging options tells `bitcoind` to print out information about the transactions that it rejects from the mempool, including why. You can thus enable this option and tail and grep the `debug.log` file looking for the string

```
was not accepted
```

This string is only found in the `mempoolrej` message which is of the form

```
<txid> from peer=<peer id> was not accepted: <reason>
```

The `reason` you are looking for is `txn-mempool-conflict`. So you can tail and grep for the entire string:

```
was not accepted: txn-mempool-conflict
```

Then with some bash-fu you can make this notify you whenever this string is found in the `debug.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Normally bitcoind does not give such notification, but Bitcoind supports connection via ZeroMQ. Mayby by this interface you will get more notification.